# iOS 5 - AFNetworking - Uploading Video

Tags: iphone, ios5, upload, afnetworking

For my app, users will be able to record a video or choose a video from their photo album and through a php script upload the video file to the server. To upload the file to the server, I am using AFNetworking. I originally tried to upload the video from the photo album, but since I could not get that to work I added a video (that I know uploads fine through an html front I made for the php script) into the main bundle.

The code is:

```
NSString *vidURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:vidURL]];

    NSLog(@"The test vid's url is %@.",vidURL);

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"http://www.mywebsite.com"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
    {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"test.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"]; 
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

My PHP script runs fine as I am able to upload the same video via an HTML form. The above code fails to get to the setUploadProgressBlock, however.

Does anything stick out as broken to anyone or is there something else I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I used to fix the problem:

```
httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *afRequest = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) 
    {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
    }];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:afRequest];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    }];

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {NSLog(@"Success");} 
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);}];
    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the objects are getting deallocated immediately. Make the AFHTTPClient an instance variable of your class or subclass it and make it a singleton.

More Important: Replace this line:

```
[operation start];
```

with:

```
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Just curious why you would use [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation] over [operation start]? Most of the AFNetworking's calls [operation start]. Also, still getting a null return value for the operation's response.

Comment: okay, [operation start] should also work but why not use the NSOperationQueue of AFHTTPClient? This automatically schedules the execution of the requests and is better for concurrent operations. Note it is an error to do both.